# what is the effective way of inserting huge data with complex data types in Postgres using JDBC

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc, complex-data-types

We have a requirement to insert huge records in to postgres. In sqlServer we have used TableTypes for this. In postgres we have to do in something similar and i have done something like below.

I have a table MyuserDefinedTable with columns like

- id  `uuid`
- date `timestamp`
- value `integer`
- name  `String`

I have created a Function in postgres like,

```
CREATE or replace function myuserDefinedTableupdatefunction(
    _table_name regclass,
    _column_names text,
    _insert_arr MyuserDefinedTable[]) returns text as
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %s(%s) SELECT * FROM unnest($1)',_table_name , _column_Names)   
        USING _insert_arr;          
    RETURN 'Saved'; 
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RETURN 'Failure';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Its working fine if i call the function, by passing params directly, like below,

```
Select myuserDefinedTableupdatefunction ('MyuserDefinedTable','ID,date,value,NAME', ARRAY[ROW('a1563404-0d1d-11ea-b563-3ca82a1c6940', '2019-11-21 00:00:00.0,100.00','3','hello'),ROW('b5563404-7d1d-11ea-b563-3ca82a1c6940', '2019-11-22 00:00:00.0,100.00','4','hii')]::MyuserDefinedTable[])
```

But its not executing (throwing error like, 'missed left Paranthesis' even though i ensured everything is fine syntactically) if i try to insert values dynamically through JDBC like below,

```
String query=Select myuserDefinedTableupdatefunction ('MyuserDefinedTable', 'ID,date,value,NAME', ARRAY[?]::MyuserDefinedTable[])

Object[] arr = objectList.toArray(new Object[0]);  // Object List has list of params appended like ( [0]: a1563404-0d1d-11ea-b563-3ca82a1c6940,2019-11-21 00:00:00.0,100.0,3,hello

// [1]: b1563404-0d1d-11ea-b563-3ca82a1c6940,2019-11-22 00:00:00.0,100.0,4,hi)
Array array = getSession().getConnection().createArrayOf("MyuserDefinedTable", arr);
ps.setArray(1, array);
```

Can anyone help me with the above?

Also, the execution time of inserting huge records is taking almost double than normal insert statements.

Is there any effective way of inserting huge records in to Postgres DB using an array with a complex datatype?

**Edit**:   With some suggestions, I also tried using CopyManager like,

```
    String sql = "COPY MyuserDefinedTable FROM stdin CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','";
        BaseConnection pgcon = (BaseConnection)getSession().getConnection();
        CopyManager mgr = new CopyManager(pgcon);
        try {
            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Testing/data.csv"))); // The file is my local system
            long rowsaffected  = mgr.copyIn(sql, in);
            System.out.print(rowsaffected);
        }
```

But the above code returns **0** rows effected.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: That function will really slow things down.  Have you tried using the CopyManager: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Comment: I think a regular INSERT statement using `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` would be a much easier way (no need to cope with SQL arrays in Java) and probable faster as well. Applying SQL Server coding style to a DBMS that is so much different is bound to bring more problems.

Comment: @Jeremy I haven't tried it, can you please help me, how to use it in the above context?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We already have code with addBatch() and executeBatch, but my superiors are very keen to handle TVP efficiently in Postgres

Comment: There is no such thing as a TVP in Postgres - simple as that. And trying to mimic one will only result in mediocre solutions Your superiors need to migrate their mindset too.

Answer (score 1):

*Thanks All*

The below solution worked for me, I tried using COPY function by passing Byte Arrays instead of getting data from files (As we are using Cloud, I came to know that file permissions will be a problem in AWS).

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141798

```
        List<String> valueList=myData();

        //Converting ArrayList to ByteArray
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            for (String element : valueList) {
                out.writeBytes(element);
            }       
            bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        }
        if(bytes!=null) {
            try(ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)){

                // Copying records into table using COPY..FROM and COPYMANAGER in Postgres
                String sql = "COPY "+tableName+" FROM stdin delimiter ','  NULL AS 'null' ";
                BaseConnection pgcon = (BaseConnection)getSession().getConnection();
                CopyManager mgr = new CopyManager(pgcon);                   
                long rowsEffected=mgr.copyIn(sql,input);                                        
            }
        }
```

This seems faster than the way that i posted in the question above.